# I want both distinct and nondistinct records in join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  distinct referrals.listing_id,submissions.listing_name
FROM submissions
INNER JOIN referrals ON referrals.listing_id=submissions.listing_id;
```

if i do

```
SELECT  distinct referrals.listing_id,submissions.listing_name,referrals.timestamp
FROM submissions
INNER JOIN referrals ON referrals.listing_id=submissions.listing_id;
```

it gives me many others records without `distinct listing_id`

i want `distinct listing_id` with their timestamps(which are not distinct but are according to `distinct listing_id`)

Comment: Know your RDBMS. MySQL <> SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregation, if you want one row per listing.  For instance:

```
SELECT r.listing_id, s.listing_name, max(r.timestamp) as most_recent_timestamp
FROM submissions s INNER JOIN
     referrals r
     ON r.listing_id = s.listing_id
GROUP BY r.listing_id, s.listing_name;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all the expressions in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Missing `GROUP BY`.